# What to do when a Primary ACS appliance fails within a Split ACS 5.6 deployment?

Tags: cisco

Could anyone offer advice on this scenario?

Environment: 2 x ACS 5.6 appliances
- Primary ACS Appliance (+Log collector)
- Secondary ACS Appliance

Test process
1. Simulated network connection failure on Primary appliance
2. Test switch able to authenticate against Secondary appliance 
3. Able to login to Secondary - Read only, no administration function, unable to view logs as log collector also

If administration required what is the best option for the secondary appliance?
- Promote to primary?
- Request local mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after some searching I found cisco doc with a scenario reference:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_secure_access_control_system/5-6/user/guide/acsuserguide/admin_operations.html#75607

Scenario covered in failover section

"ACS 5.6 allows you to configure multiple ACS instances for a deployment scenario. Each deployment can have one primary and multiple secondary ACS servers.

Scenario: Primary ACS goes down in a Distributed deployment"

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.